# next_record called with no query pending

Tags: php

I want to call a `PHP` function :

```
$rights =  $user->recupererDroitCreateur($_SESSION[CODE_USER]);
```

Code of recupererDroitCreateur is :

```
function recupererDroitCreateur($user_id) {
    $ret = array();
    $sSQL = "SELECT cm.class_menu_code
                 FROM menu m
                 LEFT JOIN classe_menu cm
                 ON m.class_menu_code = cm.class_menu_code
                 WHERE m.menu_deleted = 0 AND m.menu_visible = 1 AND cm.class_menu_parent IS NULL AND cm.class_menu_deleted = 0 
                 ORDER BY cm.class_menu_lib, m.menu_titre";
    $this->db->query($sSQL);
    while ( $this->db->next_record() ) {
        $code = $this->db->f('class_menu_code');
        $strMenus = $code.";";
        $this->recupererMenus($code, $code, $user_id, $strMenus);
    }
    return (explode(";", $strMenus));
}
```

Code of recupererMenus is :

```
function recupererMenus($classRoot, $classParentDirect, $user_id, &$menus)
{
    $sSQL1 = "SELECT class_menu_code FROM classe_menu WHERE class_menu_parent = '$classParentDirect' AND class_menu_deleted = 0";
    $this->db->query($sSQL1);
    while ( $this->db->next_record() ) {
        $this->recupererMenus($classRoot, $this->db->f('class_menu_code'), $user_id, $menus);
    }

    $sSQL = "SELECT m.menu_code
             FROM menu m
             LEFT JOIN classe_menu cm
             ON m.class_menu_code = cm.class_menu_code
             WHERE m.menu_deleted = 0 AND m.menu_visible = 1 AND cm.class_menu_parent = '$classParentDirect' AND cm.class_menu_deleted = 0 
             ORDER BY cm.class_menu_lib, m.menu_titre";

    $this->db->query($sSQL);
    while ( $this->db->next_record() ) 
    {
        $menus .= $this->db->f('menu_code').";";
    }
}
```

In runtime there is the error `next_record called with no query pending` : the error output tells the lines which cause the error and it says the line corresponding to this statement : `while ( $this->db->next_record() ) {` , there is also line pointing to the statement `$this->recupererMenus($code, $code, $user_id, $strMenus);`

So what is wrong in my codes ?

Comment: what's the framework you use?

Comment: there is. `next_record` is not a PHP builtin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `recupererMenus` you recursively call `recupererMenus`. Since there's no query identifier passed to `next_record`, using multiple `query`s will create a big mess.. When you return from the recursive call, you are going to try to fetch the next record with `next_record` for a previous `query`, but your DB framework doesn't know about this..

I don't know the framework you use, but you either have to pass the identifier (if it's possible at all), or first fetch all the results, and then do the recursive call.

Comment: our coworkers created the builtin next_record inside a class. It's inside the `db`'s class.

Comment: till now I don't understand because I looked the implementation of the next_record and it has no parameter.

Comment: as I said, you have to fetch all the records first, or you have to patch your framework.